# Support multiple screens for android and libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I was starting with game development for android and i have one question or i need suggestion. At the moment i have problem if the same picture i use for all screen (mobile tablets itd itd), in one screens look cool but other strange. How can i slove this problem. 
Yes i know i must suport for other widths. But the main problem is what i must support,

- denisty,
- size?
- resolution

or maybe small/normal/large etc..screens?
What is the bast way to support,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using latest version of libgdx. The stage.setViewPOrt changed.

```
stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(width, height)); // OR
stage.setViewport(new StretchViewport(width, height));
```

or

```
stage = new Stage(new ExtendViewport(width, height)); // OR
stage.setViewport(new ExtendViewport(width, height));
```

to fit your difference ratio of screen.

Comment: where is tutorial wor use this or how use this ?

Comment: actually you can easily google it. http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3322

Comment: ok god if i need detected with android for screen and past 5 lenghts of pictures

Comment: like 32*32, 64*64, 128*128 or somthing diferent.

Comment: You need to implement it yourself by ResolutionFileResolver. You cannot use the structure in android drawable.

Comment: maybi like that if i have got width<=480, width <=800 width <=1200 width <= 1600 like that? if width is small i import small picture, if width 1600px i import large picture...?

Comment: Actually the class just manage the naming for you. Then select difference image when you pass the screen to it.

Comment: but i have one big problem, the android have got a lot of different resolutions if i want support all i need too much time ?

Comment: Add that is always a problem on android :D

Answer (score 0):

If you use sprite batch then you can use batch.setprojectionmatrix(yourOrthographicCamera.combined) in this way the sprites will resize automatically  . if you use stage and actors then search in google about libGDX stage viewports .

Comment: where is tutorial wor use this or how use this ?

Comment: i use setprojectionmatrix :) becus i have sprite and batch system

Comment: you will exactly need yo use buttons as actors. so try to learn viewport too)